# Index for Hedge fund, Private Equity, Venture Capital

Tags: index, hedge-fund

We have index for stock market, like S&P500, Nikkei 225, etc.

I wonder if we have any index for hedge funds, private equity or venture capital?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with indexes for private equity or venture capital.  For hedge funds, there are various indexes, with the best-regarded ones provided by [HFR](https://www.hedgefundresearch.com/index.php?fuse=indices-faq).  They include an [investable index](https://www.hedgefundresearch.com/hfrx_reg/index.php?fuse=login&loginflag=1&1416794631).

I happen to believe these indexes, even the investable one, are of *very* limited use at best.  Many hedge funds are closed, meaning they are not taking in new money.  Others have exited the index through failure, meaning there is a strong [survivorship bias](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/survivorshipbias.asp).